# Applying prices to augmented matrices

Tags: matrices

The question is as follows (translated):

> A company wants to rent 20 buses. These 2 buses are to hold 1000 people. They can choose between 3 types, 30, 40 and 60 man buses. How many of each kind can the company rent to satisfy the constraints? Solve with Gauss-Jordan.

So I solve this problem and get the solutions:

x1 (30 man)=2t-20

x2 (40 man)=40-3t

10$\leq$t$\leq$13 where t denotes the 60 man bus.

Then comes the second part of the question:

> The rent is 100.000 for the 30 man bus, 130.000 for the 40 man bus and 150.000 for the 60 man bus. Which of the solutions to question 1 will give the company the best price?

So I'm wondering if I should solve this with Gauss-Jordan (or if it is possible) or whether I can simply do like I usually do and just CHECK each solution. That doesn't seem very professional, though!

Thanks!

Comment: I did in my text book, but I'm not sure how to with the latex codes.

Comment: You should define your variables to make your solution easier to read.  What are $x_1,x_2,$ and $t$?  Presumably they have to do with the number of each type of bus, but I can't figure out what $t$ should be to make the constraint $10 \le t \le 13$

Comment: The problem statement asks for Gauss-Jordan, so that is what you should do.  In the real world, checking each solution is a fine approach, though not always the least effort.

Comment: Hi Ross. I clarified my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, as long as your working is sound, then it doesn't matter what you do to arrive at the correct solution and so you'll generally want to use whichever method gets you there the fastest. In this case, pretty much no other method will require less effort than simply substituting the four values of $t$ you have. For other questions though you may have many more cases to check and so this may become unfavourable, in which case you may want to use a calculus approach.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I suspected. Unbelievable that it doesn't note this in my book.